# Java List with two Objects inside: List<Object o, Object p>

Tags: java, list, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to do the following?

```
List<Object o, Object p> listWithTwoObjects;
```

I want to retrieve data from a database and save it into this list, concretely in this way

```
Query query = "retrieve all posts and username, which this user posted";
List<Object o, Object p> userAndPost = query.getResultList();
```

`o` is the username, and `p` is the post. I can then render this to my template and show each post with its user.

My question is about the List with two Objects inside. Is it possible and if yes, how and where is the documentation for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can define a `Pair` class as follows:

```
public class Pair
{
    String username;
    int post;

    public Pair(String username, int post)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.post = post;
    }
}
```

and then simply use `List<Pair>`, for example:

```
List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();
pairs.add(new Pair("doniyor", 12345));

// ...

Pair p = pairs.get(0);
System.out.pritnln(p.username); // doniyor
System.out.pritnln(p.post); // 12345
```

Comment: Or even better, name them ´userName´ and ´post´

Comment: if i render this to my template as a json, then it will look like this: 

``["username1":"post1","username2":"post2","username3":"post3"]``, right?

Comment: You can make the Pair class even more generic by 

Pair<K,V> { 
  K key; 
  V value;

  public K getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public V getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}

That way, you can reuse your class to a greater extent.

Comment: I suggest avoiding the fully generic `Pair` class, since `key` and `value` are really not very useful names for variables and don't tell you what the data is actually supposed to mean.

Comment: @Wasserman thanks Louis, i think ftom2 has given a good option, but i take a look and give a shot. lets c which is the best one..

Comment: @Wasserman see your point with names not making sense, but if we're going down that road I'd call the class UsernamePostPair :-D

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly you want to have all posts of a user, so instead of using List you should use Map:

```
Map<String,List<Post>> map = new HashMap<String,List<Post>>();
```

Then, the key(String) would be the userName and the value would be a list of Post objects.

Comment: if i render this to my template as a json, then it will look like this: 
``["username1":"post1","username2":"post2","username3":"post3"]`` , right?

Comment: More likeley it would look like: [{"username1":{"post1","post2"},"username2":{"post1","post2"}]

Comment: You can use a Multimap instead. It is effectively a Map with Collection-based values. It is part of the Guava library.

Comment: You can use a Multimap instead. It is effectively a Map with Collection-based values. It is part of the Guava library.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a list like that, but you can use a Map, with username as key and post as value. Or is there a particular reason to use a list?